# Angular 5: Dynamic Templates

Tags: angular, angular5

Angular 5 [removed the runtime compiler](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20156), and my understanding is that it's now impossible to dynamically compile templates due to this.

So I need to come up with another way of accomplishing what I need; hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a video platform written in Angular. People can post comments on the videos, and can include a timestamp somewhere in their comment, such as:

```
Great video! Maybe a bit more colour at 00:32, make it look more like 01:20?
```

I'm matching each timestamp using Regex, and attempting to add a call to the component in the timestamp link:

```
const exp = /\b[0-9]*\:[0-9]*\b/;
comment.commentText = comment.commentText.replace(exp, (match) =>
{
     return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="jumpTo(\'' + match + '\')">' + match + '</a>';
});
```

With the ability to compile a custom template now missing, how can I get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say this is only true if your talking about Ahead of Time compilation of components. I'm starting to work on a way to do dynamic angular templates, and I've got to think it's still possible if you aren't using AOT.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a `TaggedCommentComponent` which accepts the original comment text as input, parses it, and creates an array of interleaved texts and time tag links, to build on your example, it would be:

```ts
[
  'Great video! Maybe a bit more colour at ',
  '00:32',
  ', make it look more like ',
  '01:20',
  '?'
]
```

Then in the template for this component use something like:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let t of texts; let even=even">
  <ng-container *ngIf="even">
    <a (click)="jumpTo(t)">{{t}}</a>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!even">{{t}}</ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Indeed, this would work in this particular example. However, since I want to expand it further to parse lots of other things as well, this will end up getting extremely convoluted. I'm hoping there's another way.

Comment: I would still choose this approach, it is more in line with MVC, your model should include the tagged text, including every nuance, and your view should render it properly. I mean, instead of replacing HTML, why not do all the replacement operations on a string and create an appropriate data structure?